# Joining Table to Complex Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

May I ask for someone's help to complete this query in MSSMS?

Currently, I have a query able to concatenate the values in the column of ProfileItemID to one row.

This is the syntax...

```
     SELECT RoomID, ProfileItemID = 
     STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast(ProfileItemID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM 
     RoomProfile b 
     WHERE b.RoomId = a.RoomiD FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
     FROM RoomProfile a 
     Where RoomID = 1829
     GROUP BY RoomID

|----------------------------------------|
|                RoomProfile             |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         RoomID      |   ProfileItemID  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1829       |         28       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1829       |         103      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1829       |         104      |
|----------------------------------------|
```

Returns:

```
+--------+------------+
| RoomID |   Result   |
+--------+------------+
|   1829 | 28,103,104 |
+--------+------------+
```

Now, I am trying to join the first RoomProfile Table (above) with the ProfileItem table (below)

```
|----------------------------------------|
|               ProfileItem              |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     ProfileItemID   |   Description    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          28         |      Single      |
|---------------------|------------------| 
|          103        |      Double      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          104        |      Triple      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

To get

```
+------------------------+
|      Description       |
+------------------------+
| Single, Double, Triple |
+------------------------+
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
  SELECT ProfileItem.Description = 
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast(ProfileItemID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM 
  RoomProfile b 
  WHERE b.RoomId = a.RoomiD FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
  FROM RoomProfile a 
  INNER JOIN ProfileItem ON 
  RoomProfile a.ProfilteItemID = ProfileItem.ProfileItemID
  Where RoomID = 1829
  GROUP BY RoomID
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You `JOIN` your `ProfileItem` table before you messed the `RoomProfile` table.  So do your join before `XMLPATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic idea.  I didn't use your table names or column names exactly.

```
DROP TABLE #roomProfiles;
DROP TABLE #profiles;

CREATE TABLE #roomProfiles(RoomId INT, ProfileId INT);
INSERT #roomProfiles VALUES (1829, 28), (1829, 103), (1829, 104);

CREATE TABLE #profiles(ProfileId INT, Description VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT #profiles VALUES (28, 'Single'), (103, 'Double'), (104, 'Triple');

WITH
    rooms AS (
        SELECT  DISTINCT RoomId 
        FROM    #roomProfiles
    )
SELECT  r.RoomId ,
        STUFF((
            SELECT  DISTINCT ',' + p.Description 
            FROM    #roomProfiles rp 
            INNER JOIN #profiles p 
                    ON p.ProfileId = rp.ProfileId 
            WHERE   rp.RoomId = r.RoomId 
            ORDER BY ',' + p.Description 
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS RoomProfiles
FROM    rooms r
ORDER BY r.RoomId
```

Comment: Never mind. You're a genius. LoL. I need to stop jumping into conclusions.  :D